# Definition of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

One usually defines field extension $E/F$ whenever $F\subseteq E$. However, few authors
would define field extension $F/K$ whenever there is a nonzero field homomorphism $F\rightarrow E$ (see e.g Definition 3.1 page 35 here:http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/MA3D5/Galois.pdf.).
Is there any (dis)advantage in defining like in the latter case? Will something be harder (
or missed) in doing so?

Comment: You’ll have to keep track of all the morphisms and all the different fields. Other than that, it’s a generalization and has all the classical advantages and disadvantages of generalizations: Some definitions, concepts and proofs become clearer, and with others you have to be more careful. For example, naturally a intermediate extension of $E/F$ would be an extension $L/F$ such that $E/L$ is an extension, too. Now, discerning these intermediate extensions becomes more subtle. And how can you talk about the “number” of intermediate extensions? One has to be more careful.

Comment: Also, a field homomorphism $F\rightarrow E$ is also a ring homomorphism, so that the kernel of the homomorphism is an ideal of $F$.  But since $F$ is a field, its only ideals are the zero ideal or the unit ideal.  Since it's not zero, we know it isn't the unit ideal, and thus it is injective.  Thus, $F$ can be regarded as a subfield of $E$.

Comment: Maybe this link is relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411755/this-tower-of-fields-is-being-ridiculous

Comment: @Hurkyl. Your link/answer brought me exactly the discussion I've been looking for. It is a pity that textbooks don't usually make any comment on this regard.

Comment: @Hurkyl. Thanks a lot! Btw, How do select your answer as the official  one? I'm new to this community.

Comment: I hadn't made it an answer; I thought it only worth a comment. But if that really answered your question, I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411755/this-tower-of-fields-is-being-ridiculous) demonstrates some of the issues that can come up when you're in the habit of reasoning about field extensions based on subsets, but you are dealing with a situation where the fields are in a different relationship than set-theoretic inclusion.